# Cannot get registerProtocolHandler to work on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps

I'm am trying to register a custom protocol handler on a web page that is being served from http://localhost:8080

This is my code:

```
<script>
     navigator.registerProtocolHandler("web+did", "http://localhost:8080?did=%s", "did search");
</script>

<a href="web+did://123456">Search DID</a>
```

but when I click on the link, the network explorer just shows the request as "cancelled", why is it not being dispatched as "http://localhost:8080?did=123456"?

Comment: *This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS), in some or all supporting browsers* - [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/registerProtocolHandler)

Comment: I assumed (perhaps wrongly) that localhost did not fall under the "requires https" rule, similar to how service workers require https, but not from localhost.  Also, would I not see an error if it was a https issue?  I'l try to serve it from a https domain to see if it works.

Comment: I see no documentation that states "service workers require https, but not from localhost" either - are you sure? never mind, found it in the spec

Comment: ok, so I tested it under https and I'm still seeing the same behavior. When the "navigator.registerProtocolHandler" statement is in a script tag in the html body, it will fire on Firefox, but only if it's wrapped in a "window.onload".  It won't fire at all on Chrome (but it will if I manually type it into the browser console - bug?)  and it seems it isn't supported at all on Safari.  I haven't tested on IE / Edge (what's the point).

Comment: you're right about safari not supporting it - just look at the browser compatibility in the documentation

Comment: *The user will be notified that your code asked to register the protocol handler, so that they can decide whether or not to allow it* - do you get such notification?

Comment: hmm, so the behavior I'm seeing could be a bug in Chrome, unless I'm missing a trick.  It's working perfectly in Firefox, but the registerProtocolHandler statement is just not being executed in Chrome for some reason. I'm didn't get any error message or notification in Chrome

Comment: chrome + bugs ... must be a tuesday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Firefox, `navigator.registerProtocolHandler` will only work if it is included in a `window.onload` statement, or if it is executed in a function that is invoked explicitly by some user interaction (i.e. clicking on a button, which calls a function, which registers a protocol handler).

In Chrome, `navigator.registerProtocolHandler` can't be executed automatically, it needs to be executed in a function that is called by some user interaction.  I don't have any links to documentation to support this, I have discovered this only through my own experimentation.